# imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given

Tags: php

I am attempting to resize an image using php. I keep getting this error when I resize my image greater than 500 pixels, not sure why.

Here's the error:

```
imagecopyresampled() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given
```

Here is my code that doesn't work:

```
$resize = new ResizeImage($targetFile);
        $resize->resizeTo(1800, 1800);
        $resize->saveImage($xxlFile, 100);
```

Here's my code that does work:

```
$resize = new ResizeImage($targetFile);
        $resize->resizeTo(500, 500);
        $resize->saveImage($xxlFile, 100);
```

My script is breaking right here:

```
 $this->newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($this->resizeWidth, $this->resizeHeight);
 imagecopyresampled($this->newImage, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $this->resizeWidth, $this->resizeHeight, $this->origWidth, $this->origHeight);
```

My image is 5616 × 3744. Why cant it resize 1800 pixels wide?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this->image` is null... Your script failed when it created the destination image, could it be not enough memory allowed for such a big picture?

for a test, execute this command before running `ResizeImage()`: `ini_set("memory_limit", "1024M");`.

Also, remember loading a 5616 × 3744px image will require 63mb of memory (24bit / 3byte image), and resize it down to a 1800, 1800px (24bit / 3byte) image will require additional 10mb of memory (usually PHP is set to 64mb or 32mb of memory).

Good luck!

[EDIT]
So your 500x500x3 image will require 750kb of memory, your large picture will take 63 078 kb of memory, and together wil land on 63 828 kb, *just* under the 64mb memory limit :)

Comment: You're the best. That's what it was, memory issues. Thanks for solution.